# The set of all Null linear maps is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose V and W are finite dimensional. Let $v \in V$. Let

$E = {T \in L(V, W): Tv = 0}$ where L(V, W) is the set of all linear transformations from a vector space V to a vector space W. Show that E is a subspace of L(V, W). What is dim E?

For the proof that E is a subspace I said:

It is obvious that E contains the zero element.

For $v_1, v_2 \in V, T(v_1 + v_2) = T(v_1) + T(v_2) = 0 + 0 = T(v_1 + v_2)$ by linearity of T.

For $v \in V, and c \in F, T(cv) = cT(v) = c0 = T(cv)$ By linearity of T.

Can someone verify this proof and help me figure out what the dimension of E is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_i$ be a basis for $V$ and $w_j$ be a basis for $W$. Define $T_{mn} $ by 
$T_{mn} v_i = \delta_{mi} w_n$. It is straightforward to verify that the $T_{mn}$ for a basis for $L(V,W)$, hence $\dim L(V,W) = (\dim V) (\dim W)$.

First, if $v=0$, we see that $E = L(V,W)$, hence $\dim E = (\dim V) (\dim W)$.

Now suppose $v \neq 0$.

Let $\phi: L(V,W) \to W$ be given by $\phi(T) = Tv$. Then we can write
$E = \ker \phi$ which is a subspace.

It should be straightforward to see that ${\cal R \phi} = W$ (pick any $w \in W$ and choose any $T$ such that $Tv = w$). Then it follows from the
rank nullity theorem that $\dim E = \dim \ker \phi = \dim L(V,W) -\dim W$.

Hence $\dim E = (\dim W)( (\dim V)-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to show the set $E := \{T \in L(V,W) : T(v) = 0\}$ of $T$ killing a fixed $v$ is a linear subspace of $L(V,W)$, right? Then your proof should involve $T_1 + T_2$ and $cT_1$, for $T_1, T_2 \in E$ and $c$ a scalar, rather than $v_1 + v_2$ and $cv$.

For the dimension, one way to go is to pick a basis of $V$ including $v$ and any basis for $W$. Consider what the matrix with respect to these bases of an element $T$ in your subspace $E$ must look like.

Answer (score 0):

Here dim(L(V,W))=mn where dim(V)=m & dim(W)=m. Now considering the m*n matrices. We get if dim(E)>0 then there exist co ordinate vectors for which T(v) not equal to zero (Exercise). Hence dim(E)=0.

Comment: This can't be true in general. For example, the set of linear functionals on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that vanish on $e_1$ is not empty (take $Tx = x_2$).

Comment: No I told it if it is true for all v in V. As he is taking v1 & v2 arbit in V thats why...

Comment: In your case copper.hat T does not vanish on e2 hence in R2.

Comment: The question is about a specific $v$, not all $v$.

Comment: It is obvious that E contains the zero element.

For v1,v2∈V,T(v1+v2)=T(v1)+T(v2)=0+0=T(v1+v2) by linearity of T.

For v∈V,andc∈F,T(cv)=cT(v)=c0=T(cv) By linearity of T.

Comment: How can he choose v1, v2 then??

Comment: The question is about the space of $T$ such that $Tv=0$ for some **fixed** $v$. (Otherwise the problem would be immediate.)